# How to use explode for three variables

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I am storing array in the following way

```
$pos[$k] = $total[$k]." / ".$posts_ids[$k]." / ".$time[$k];
```

I am using following way to extract the value from the pos array.

```
$a = $b = array();
foreach ($pos as $key => $value){
  list($a[$key], $b[$key], $t[$key]) = explode('/', $value);
  array_multisort($a, SORT_DESC, SORT_NUMERIC, $b ,$t);
}
```

But i am not able to extract the value  of the variable $t as well as not able to sort it without change there position of array.

Comment: Please consider formatting your code in the future - I have fixed it for you, for now. Also consider posting your example code *here* instead of behind a link. That makes questions more self contained and simple to read.

Comment: Yeah i am trying but Stackoverflow don't allowing me with < Pre > tag

Comment: Then read the styling guide that's freely available if you but click on the question mark to the top right of the editor. Also, study what I and eis did to your post to learn how.

Comment: OKay will do it ! now stop off topic reply !

Comment: Try doing the sorting outside the `foreach` loop.

Comment: `$a = $b = array();`<-- best break this up over 2 lines, arrays are assigned by reference, so this `$b === $a` will always be true

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Working Dude , now i want to sort without losing index

Comment: @SSK, then you'll have to look into `asort` and the like...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't defined `t` as an array in your code, which shouldn't be a problem unless you have no values (but, in that case, you would get a warning).

As for [multisort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php), the correct syntax would be

```
array_multisort($a, $b, $t, SORT_NUMERIC, SORT_DESC);
```

but **it's not very clear what you want to do**, and it might be more convenient to organize differently the parsing of values (e.g. in a multidimensional array instead of multiple arrays, or use a custom sort function).

```
<?php

        $a = array();
        $b = array();
        $t = array();

        $values = array("5/7/12","1/9/3");

        foreach($values as $key => $value)
        {
                list($a[$key], $b[$key], $t[$key]) = explode('/', $value);
        }
        array_multisort($a, $b, $t, SORT_NUMERIC, SORT_DESC);

        print_r($a);
        print_r($b);
        print_r($t);
?>
```

> as well as not able to sort it without change there position of array.

That is by design. `array_multisort` sorts on the *first* array you pass, which is `$a`. The corresponding elements in the other arrays will be sorting according to the position of the items in `$a`.

For example if the first element of `$a` is the smallest, it will be placed last in `SORT_DESC`. But since the first element of `$a` is last, the last element of `$t` will also be put last within `$t`, *whatever its value*.

If you want `$t` to "rule" the sort, you must put it first.

If you want all three arrays to be independently sorted, you must not use `array_multisort`.

Comment: Hey ! it is working now! But if we go for multidimensional array it is not working properly.

Comment: Updated my answer; the function *is* working properly, but maybe you don't agree on what is *proper* :-)

Comment: The same as my SO ID. I'm not very original, I'm afraid :-D